# how to make a report in stimul soft with dynamic columns

Tags: c#, report, stimulsoft

I have a few warehouses with some columns like *name*, *location* and other stuff and I have products that the user can add to the database. Each warehouse has some quantity of each product.

I want to add columns from products and to count the quantity of each product in each warehouse, like this:

| WareHouse | Column B | Product A | Product B | Product C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WH1 | A | 50 | 30 | 60 |
| WH2 | B | 70 | 12 | 25 |
| WH3 | C | 35 | 0 | 12 |
| WH4 | D | 0 | 0 | 10 |

How can I obtain this result, especially when a user adds new columns ?

I got some results with cross data but I don't know what format of data need to be and what filters I need to set.
I found [this](https://forum.stimulsoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=57347)  but I don't know the steps to get the result I want.